# Who has a winning strategy for a finite number of moves, the first or the second player?

Tags: polynomials, combinatorial-game-theory

Two players play the next game: They start with the polynomial
$$2013x^2+2012x+2011$$and play by turns. Each player in his turn subtracts from the current polynomial one of the following polynomials: $x^2, x, x^2-x+1$ or $x^2+x-1$ of his choice. If after a move the resulting polynomial has an integer root, then the player who made the move loses. Who has a winning strategy for a finite number of moves, the first or the second player?

Comment: What is an "entire" root ? Do you mean integer ?

Comment: It's "integer root"

Comment: The game is not guaranteed to be finite. You should define when the game is a tie.